# JsonFormatter ReferenceLoopHandling

Tags: c#, json.net, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

I have been struggling with this for a few days now, not finding any joy in any solutions I have found so far.

The project is built using Entity Framework 6 and WebAPI 2.
I have changed the my WebApiConfig settings to

```
        config.Formatters.Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```

There seems to be an infinite loop happening now with a System Out Of Memory Exception being thrown.

I cant seem to find the correct way to do this.

I have tried this within the WebAPI Method too, still the same symptom.

```
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetCustomer_Title(int id)
    {
        Customer_Title c = await db.Customer_Title.FindAsync(id);
        if (c == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(c, new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        });


        return Ok(json);
    }
```

and in my Customer_Title Class

```
 public partial class Customer_Title
    {

        public Customer_Title()
        {
            Customer = new HashSet<Customer>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int TitleID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string TitleDescription { get; set; }

        public int InstanceID { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual ICollection<Customer> Customer { get; set; }

        public virtual System_Instance System_Instance { get; set; }
    }
```

The [JsonIgnore] Attribute seems to be doing nothing.

Comment: You should probably also disable lazy loading. I think a whole fleet of adhering entities is dragged in from the database.

Comment: Disabling Lazy Loading didn't help either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use DTO instead of Entity framework entity,
For example:

```
    class PersonDTO {
       public Name {get; set;}
    }

    var person = context.People.First();
    var personDTO = new PersonDTO{
      Name = person.Name    
    }

   var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(personDTO);
```

Comment: Is this the only way? IS their no way to do this without and intermediary DTO?

Comment: For web api you don't need dtos, web api handles it I think

Comment: this is not an answer - i.e. use a different object!